# Why does the *= operator change numpy arrays out of scope?

Tags: python, variables, operators, variable-assignment, numpy-ndarray

I just came across this weird behaviour (at least for me) of the *= operator for numpy arrays in python. If I pass a local variable (ndarray), lets call it x,  to a function and then modify x for example via x*= 2, this change is propagated to the scope where I called the function. If I do the same but using x = x*2 I do not see this behaviour. Why is that? I was expecting that x*=2 and x=x*2 is identical. I observe this only for numpy arrays. Thank you for your help, I also attached an example code.

```
import numpy as np

def my_func1(x_func):
    x_func *= 2
    return None

def my_func2(x_func):
    x_func = x_func * 2
    return None

def my_func():
    x = np.array([1])  # expect x to keep this value in the scope of my_func
    my_func2(x)
    print(x)  # x still [1]
    my_func1(x)
    print(x)  # x changed to [2]!

my_func()

Out:
[1]
[2]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between add and iadd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402501/difference-between-add-and-iadd)

Comment: Same apply for operators like `mul`/`__mul__` vs `imul`/`__imul__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some operations, such as += and *=, act in place to modify an existing array rather than create a new one. That is why when the first function was called then the array from the main function was modified.

```
def my_func1(x_func):
    x_func *= 2
    return None
```

The new array was not returned in the second function after modification(x_func = x_func * 2) and it was a simple assignment operation.

```
def my_func2(x_func):
    x_func = x_func * 2
    return None
```

so its value was not modified in the main function(my_func()).

Reference: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html#basic-operations

Comment: Thank you, also for referencing the link here. I was aware of that but was surprised that this even works across different scopes.