# Find Perfect Number using While loop in Python

Tags: python

There is no error in this code but its not printing the result. Here, what could be the problem.

```
# Using WHILE LOOP
num = int(input('Enter any positive integer: '))
sum1 = 0
i = 1

if num <= 0:
    print('Invalid Number.')
else:
    while(i < num):
        if num % i == 0:
            sum1 = sum1 + i
            i = i + 1
    
    if sum1 == num:
        print(num, "is a perfect number")
    else:
        print(num, "is not a perfect number")
```

Comment: Think what happen when `num % i == 0` is False..

Comment: You have an infinite loop if `num % i` is not 0. Move `i = i + 1` out of the `if`.

Comment: You have no `else` on your `while`, so if `num % i != 0` you enter an infinite loop. Just put some `else: i = i + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here:
`if num % i == 0`. The `==` operator checks if the **remainder** of `num/i` is 0. If yes, then it updates `i`. But, if `num % i` is not 0, then it never adds anything to `i`. So, with each iteration, you are doing the same thing: `num % i == 0`.

You need to bring `i = i + 1` outside `if` statement because `i` should increase regardless of whether the number is divisible or not.

Also, it is better to use `i+=1`. See [difference between add and iadd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39402501/difference-between-add-and-iadd)

```
while(i < num):
    if num % i == 0:
        sum1 = sum1 + i
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: Yes! It was logical error. It solved my problem. Thank You!.

Answer (score 0):

You set `if num % i == 0: i += 1`, so `if num % i != 0`, `i` will not be updated. you just add else after `if num % i == 0`.

```
num = int(input('Enter any positive integer: '))
sum1 = 0
i = 1

if num <= 0:
    print('Invalid Number.')
else:
    while(i < num):
        if num % i == 0:
            sum1 = sum1 + i
            i += + 1
        else:
            i+=1
    if sum1 == num:
        print(num, "is a perfect number")
    else:
        print(num, "is not a perfect number")
```

Answer (score 0):

You set up an infinite while loop.

If `i < num` is true and `num % i == 0` is false, the while loop will run infinitely. You can verify this by using a print statement inside the while loop. Like this:

```
while(i < num): 
        if num % i == 0:
            sum1 = sum1 + i
            i = i + 1
        print('Passed the if statement')
```

If `Passed the if statement` gets printed multiple times then `num % i == 0` is false and the if statement got ignored, and the while loop keeps running and ignoring the if statement again and again.

Once you figured out the problem, you could find out many solutions. I could suggest moving the incrementation of i out of the if statement so that whenever `num % i == 0` results to false, i would be incremented and checked again. So the while loop could look like this:

```
while(i < num): 
        if num % i == 0:
            sum1 = sum1 + i
        i = i + 1
```